# Object array value in ngRepeat not getting updated on UI

Tags: angularjs

I have some data in the form of array, which I am converting into an object using `_.groupBy(data, ""filter")`. After grouping, it looks like this

```
$scope.data = {"Key1" : [{}, {}], "Key2" : [{}] }
```

I am looping this object using ngRepeat, and have a directive inside the ngRepeat like below.

```
<div ng-repeat = "(key, value) in data">
    <my-directive id={{$index}} group = "data[key]"></my-directive>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is, on refreshing and calling the service again, the updated array of keys is not displayed on the UI. However, if any new key is added in the data object, only then UI is updating.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: maybe I'm just not understanding your sample, but why would you convert an array into an object, and then use `ng-repeat` which is meant for arrays on the object?

Comment: Post the code how you update data with service.